# input с пробелами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как можно реализовать ввод в `input` в таком формате `12 345`,`1 345` с пробелом ?

html:

```
<input type="text" name="slider">
```

Без плагина **mask**, а с помощью:

```
input.val() replace
```

Comment: https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Comment: а с одним replace мне кажется не получится, ведь регулярках нет понятия начать с конца, а 12 345 пробел нужно именно с конца вставлять, с начала это будет 123 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Красивее у меня не получается..

```js
const InputFormatType = {
    THOUSAND: 3
};
const decorator = ( value, format = InputFormatType.THOUSAND ) => value
    .split( '' )
    .filter( char => char !== " " )
    .reverse()
    .reduce( ( result, char, index ) => result += (( index >= format && index % format === 0 ? " " : "" ) + char), "" )
    .split( '' )
    .reverse()
    .join( '' );

const input = document.body.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', input_inputHandler);

function input_inputHandler( { target } ){
  target.value = decorator( target.value );
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Классно! Только не помогло в моей ситуации задам еще вопрос))

Answer (score 2):

Нашла решение `.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "`:

```js
var val = $('input').val();

$('input').val(val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ") );

$('input').change(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      valIn = $this.val(),  
  valInNew = valIn.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");
  
  $this.val(valInNew);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<input type="text" value="12345">
```

Comment: используйте `keyup` вместо `change`

Comment: @Alex, спасибо, учту!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Вот так лучше будет - https://jsfiddle.net/hvbevdoj/

Comment: Только обязательно нужно пробелы нужно каждый раз удалять, а то у меня вот так получилось - `123 456 789 123 45 6 661` и даже вот так `3 45 6 661 5 559`.

Answer (score 1):

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

```
$('input[name=slider]').mask('000 000 000', {reverse: true});
```